# LaTeX Flowchart Error

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

[image]

I am working to generate this image and came across this LaTeX code but it flattens the image when I ran it.

```
% Flowchart
% Author: Qrrbrbirlbel
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,backgrounds,
  positioning-plus,node-families,calc}
\tikzset{
  basic box/.style = {
    shape = rectangle,
    align = center,
    draw  = #1,
    fill  = #1!25,
    rounded corners},
  header node/.style = {
    Minimum Width = header nodes,
    font          = \strut\Large\ttfamily,
    text depth    = +0pt,
    fill          = white,
    draw},
  header/.style = {%
    inner ysep = +1.5em,
    append after command = {
      \pgfextra{\let\TikZlastnode\tikzlastnode}
      node [header node] (header-\TikZlastnode) at (\TikZlastnode.north) {#1}
      node [span = (\TikZlastnode)(header-\TikZlastnode)]
        at (fit bounding box) (h-\TikZlastnode) {}
    }
  },
  hv/.style = {to path = {-|(\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}},
  vh/.style = {to path = {|-(\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}},
  fat blue line/.style = {ultra thick, blue}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.2cm, thick, nodes = {align = center},
    >=latex]
  \node[Minimum Width = loop, shape = ellipse, fill = red] (imp-sol)
    {ellipsoid box};
  \node[Minimum Width = loop, fill = yellow, below = of imp-sol] (rec-box)
    {rectangular box, and very wiiiiiiiiiiiiiiide\\2nd line};
  \node[shift = (left:.5*x_node_dist)] at
    ($(imp-sol.west|-imp-sol.south)!.5!(rec-box.north west)$) (for-1)
    {formula 1};
  \node[shift = (right:.5*x_node_dist)] at
    ($(imp-sol.east|-imp-sol.south)!.5!(rec-box.north east)$) (for-2)
    {formula 2};
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \node[fit = (for-1)(for-2)(imp-sol)(rec-box), basic box = blue,
      header = DMFT loop] (dmft-l) {};
  \end{scope}
  \path[very thick, blue, hv] (rec-box) edge[->] (for-1) edge[<-] (for-2)
                              (imp-sol) edge[->] (for-2) edge[<-] (for-1);

  \node[east above = of dmft-l, basic box = green, header = DMFT prelude]
    (dmft-p) {Math and text math and text math and text\\
              math and text math and text math and text};
  \node[north left = of dmft-l, basic box = green, header = $\rho$ update,
     shift = (down:y_node_dist)] (rho)
    {Much more text much more text\\much more text much more text};
  \node[basic box = blue, header = DFT part, anchor = north] at
    (dmft-p.north-|rho) (dft) {So much text so much text so much text\\
    I think I need \texttt{tikz-lipsum}\\or something like that.};
  \node[basic box = green, anchor = north] at
    ($(dft.north east)!.5!(dmft-p.north west)$) (upd) {update\\$math$};
  \path[fat blue line, <-, dashed, vh] (rho) edge
    ({$(rho.south)!.5!(dmft-l.south)$}-|dmft-l.south west);
  \path[fat blue line, ->]
    ({$(upd.south)!.5!(dmft-p.south)$}-|dmft-p.south west)
    coordinate (@) edge[<-, solid] coordinate[pos=.15] (@s)
    coordinate[pos=.9] (@e) (@-|dft.east)
    {[every edge/.append style=dashed, vh] (@s) edge[<-] (upd) (@e) edge (upd)}
    (h-rho) edge[dashed] (dft)
    ($(dmft-p.south)!.5!(dmft-p.south east)$)
    coordinate (@) edge (@|-dmft-l.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I do *not* reproduce the output you show. Did you download the `positioning-plus` library, and if so, from where?

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat , from https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibrarypositioning-plus.code.tex. Also `node-familiea` from https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibrarynode-families.code.tex. Since here is 02:38, I will do to my bed :-)

Comment: @Zarko Then I must have an older version. I do not get the output shown there. Do you?

Comment: I did not download that library i just wan the latex file i found. PS i useing Overleaf

Comment: This explains it, I think. `positioning-plus` is not a standard library, and needs to be installed in some way. `overleaf` is very good at suppressing error messages **SIGH** such that you probably did not even notice that the library does not get found, nor did you see the error messages resulting from styles not being defined as a consequence. So you need to download `tikzlibrarypositioning-plus.code.tex` from e.g. @Zarko' comment and install it (don't ask me how that works on overleaf). Or do the diagram without that library.

Comment: @ajpat When you run that code on Overleaf you'll see a small red box with a number in it right next to the big green "Recompile" button. That means the code threw some errors. Click on that red box to see the errors. In this case the first error says *I did not find the tikz library positioning-plus ...*. Error messages aren't always very clear, but here at least it gives a good clue. I  I don't think one can install new packages etc. for general use on Overleaf, so it's just a matter of uploading the file `tikzlibrarypositioning-plus.code.tex` to the project. (@Schrödinger'scat)

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun: some attempt to add some features which are a bit reminiscent of the nice `positioning-plus`. This cannot compete with the library, but is sufficient to more or less reproduce the diagram,

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newbox\eqnodebox
\tikzset{equal size/.style={execute at begin
    node={\setbox\eqnodebox=\hbox\bgroup},
    execute at end node={\egroup\eqmakebox[#1][c]{\copy\eqnodebox}}},
    equal size/.default=A}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{widthofeqsizenode}{1}{\begingroup%
\ifcsname eqp@this@#1\endcsname
\edef\pgfutil@tempx{\csname eqp@this@#1\endcsname}%
\else
\edef\pgfutil@tempx{0pt}%
\fi
\pgfmathparse{\pgfutil@tempx+2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup%
}
\makeatother    

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,fit,positioning,shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{
  basic box/.style = {
    shape = rectangle,
    align = center,
    draw  = #1,
    fill  = #1!25,
    rounded corners},
  header node/.style = {
    equal size= header nodes,
    font          = \strut\Large\ttfamily,
    text depth    = +0pt,
    fill          = white,
    draw},
  header/.style = {%
    inner ysep = +1.5em,
    append after command = {
      \pgfextra{\let\TikZlastnode\tikzlastnode}
      node [header node] (header-\TikZlastnode) at (\TikZlastnode.north) {#1}
    }
  },
  east above/.style args={#1of#2}{above=#1 of #2.north east,anchor=south east},
  west above/.style args={#1of#2}{above=#1 of #2.north west,anchor=south west},
  east below/.style args={#1of#2}{below=#1 of #2.south east,anchor=north east},
  west below/.style args={#1of#2}{below=#1 of #2.south west,anchor=north west},
  north left/.style args={#1of#2}{left=#1 of #2.north west,anchor=north east},
  north right/.style args={#1of#2}{right=#1 of #2.north east,anchor=north west},
  south left/.style args={#1of#2}{left=#1 of #2.south west,anchor=south east},
  south right/.style args={#1of#2}{right=#1 of #2.south east,anchor=south west},
  hv/.style = {to path = {-|(\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}},
  vh/.style = {to path = {|-(\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}},
  fat blue line/.style = {ultra thick, blue}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.2cm, thick, nodes = {align = center},
    >=latex]
  \node[minimum width={widthofeqsizenode("loop")}, 
  shape = ellipse, fill = red] (imp-sol)
    {ellipsoid box};
  \node[equal size=loop, fill = yellow, below = of imp-sol] (rec-box)
    {rectangular box, and very wiiiiiiiiiiiiiiide\\2nd line};
  \path (imp-sol.west) --   (rec-box.west) node[pos=0.5,left]
    (for-1)   {formula 1}
      (imp-sol.east) --     (rec-box.east) node[pos=0.5,right]
    (for-2)    {formula 2};
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \node[fit = (for-1)(for-2)(imp-sol)(rec-box), basic box = blue,
      header = DMFT loop] (dmft-l) {};
  \end{scope}
  \path[very thick, blue, hv] (rec-box) edge[->] (for-1) edge[<-] (for-2)
                              (imp-sol) edge[->] (for-2) edge[<-] (for-1);
  \node[east above=of dmft-l, basic box = green,
    header = DMFT prelude] (dmft-p) {Math and text math and text math and text\\
    math and text math and text math and text};
  \node[basic box=green,north left=of dmft-p] (upd) {update\\$math$};
  \node[basic box=blue, header=DFT part,north left=of upd] 
     (dft) {So much text so much text so much text\\
    I think I need \texttt{tikz-lipsum}\\or something like that.};
  \node[basic box = green, header = $\rho$ update]  (rho)
   at (dft|-dmft-l)
    {Much more text much more text\\much more text much more text};
  \path[fat blue line, <-, dashed, vh] (rho) edge
    ({$(rho.south)!.5!(dmft-l.south)$}-|dmft-l.south west);
   \path[fat blue line, ->]
    ([yshift=1em]dmft-p.south west) coordinate (auxR) edge[<-]
    (auxR-|dft.east) (auxR-|dft.east) coordinate (auxL)
   (upd.west) edge[<-,dashed,hv] ([xshift=5mm]auxL)
   (upd.east) edge[dashed,hv] ([xshift=-5mm]auxR)
     (header-rho) edge[dashed] (dft)
     ([xshift=-1cm]dmft-p.south east) coordinate (aux) edge (aux|-dmft-l.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To long for comment:

Testing your MWE I got correct placement of your nodes however, text was not visible. I need to add `\text=black` to all nodes style definitions. Doing this, I slightly shorter styles names and reorganized drawing of arrows:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,
                calc,
                node-families,
                positioning-plus,
                shapes.geometric,}
\tikzset{
       box/.style = {draw=#1, rounded corners, fill=#1!25,
                     align = center, text=black, inner ysep=1.5em},
        HN/.style = {draw, fill=white,
                     Minimum Width=header nodes,
                     font=\Large\ttfamily, text=black,
                     text depth=0.5ex, text height   = 2ex},
   header/.style = {%inner ysep = +1.5em,
                    append after command = {\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode}
                        node [HN] (header-\LN) at (\LN.north) {#1}
                        node (h-\LN) [span=(\LN)(header-\LN)] at (fit bounding box){}
                                            }
                    },
  hv/.style = {to path = {-|(\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}},
  vh/.style = {to path = {|-(\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}},
  fat blue line/.style = {ultra thick, blue}
        }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 1.2cm, thick, 
        nodes = {align = center},
            > = latex]
\node[Minimum Width = loop, shape = ellipse, fill = red, text=black] (imp-sol) {ellipsoid box};
\node[Minimum Width = loop, fill = yellow, text=black, below = of imp-sol] (rec-box)
    {rectangular box, and very wiiiiiiiiiiiiiiide\\2nd line};

  \node[shift = (left:.5*x_node_dist)] at
    ($(imp-sol.west|-imp-sol.south)!.5!(rec-box.north west)$) (for-1)
    {formula 1};
  \node[shift = (right:.5*x_node_dist)] at
    ($(imp-sol.east|-imp-sol.south)!.5!(rec-box.north east)$) (for-2)
    {formula 2};
\scoped[on background layer]
    \node[fit = (for-1)(for-2)(imp-sol)(rec-box), box = blue, 
      header = DMFT loop] (dmft-l) {};
%
  \path[very thick, blue, hv] (rec-box) edge[->] (for-1) edge[<-] (for-2)
                              (imp-sol) edge[->] (for-2) edge[<-] (for-1);
%%%
\node[east above = of dmft-l, box = green, header = DMFT prelude]
    (dmft-p) {Math and text math and text math and text\\
              math and text math and text math and text};
\node[north left = of dmft-l, box = green, header = $\rho$ update,
     shift = (down:y_node_dist)] (rho)
    {Much more text much more text\\much more text much more text};
\path[fat blue line, <-, dashed, vh] (rho) edge
    ({$(rho.south)!.5!(dmft-l.south)$} -| dmft-l.south west);
%%%
\node[box = blue, header = DFT part, anchor = north] at
    (dmft-p.north-|rho) (dft) 
    {So much text so much text so much text\\
    I think I need \texttt{tikz-lipsum}\\or something like that.};
%%%
\node[box = green, inner sep=3pt, below] at
    ($(dft.north east)!.5!(dmft-p.north west)$) (upd) {update\\$math$};
\draw[fat blue line, <-]
    ($(upd.south -| dmft-p.west)!0.5!(dmft-p.south west)$) coordinate (@) 
                --  coordinate[pos=.15] (@s)
                    coordinate[pos=.9]  (@e) (@ -| dft.east);
    %
    \begin{scope}[fat blue line, dashed, ->]
\draw   (upd) -| (@s);
\draw   (upd) -| (@e) 
%
        (h-rho) edge    (dft)
        ($(dmft-p.south)!.5!(dmft-p.south east)$) coordinate    (@) 
                -- (@ |- dmft-l.north);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For above result you need to compile MWE at least twice.